# ClassNotFoundException when running a JUnit test from a separate package

Tags: java, github, junit

I created a game for school and part of the assignment was to create JUnit tests but every time I run the tests I get this error

```
Class not found tests.BoardTests
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tests.BoardTests
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:688)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I'm not really sure what to do with it and if it has anything to do with GitHub. Thank you!

EDIT: attached a picture of my project setup [image]

Comment: did you check this,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381068/class-not-found-exception-when-running-junit-test?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @ShrikantHavale we aren't supposed to use or need maven for our code according to our instructor