# Class not found: "md.leonis.ServiceMagi?Test"

Tags: java, junit, classnotfound

I am writing a simple Java test using JUnit and constantly get the following error: `Class not found: "md.leonis.ServiceMagi?Test"`. I don't see any stacktrace.

Recommendations for this ticket did not help: [Class Not Found Exception when running JUnit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381068/class-not-found-exception-when-running-junit-test)

I invalidated the InteliJ Idea cache, recompiled the project, with no result. Example class:

```java
public class ServiceMagiсTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Who faced this before?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. For some mysterious reason, one letter in the class name has been replaced with a similar letter from the Russian alphabet. IDE gave a hint:

```
Identifier contains symbols from different languages: [LATIN, CYRILLIC]
Non-ASCII characters in an identifier
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Not just the IDE. The syntax coloring on SO leaves your `с` black in an otherwise blue classname. Checking for the unicode codepoint value of your character is the first thing that came to mind.