# My Maven Dependencies are ClassNotFound Exception or NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, maven, jar, dependencies

Here again (I had to rewrite it to make it more comprehensive i guess):

I got project X and project Y. They are independant from each other. While project X is working with all hibernate dependencies, I get ClassNotFound Exceptions and NoClassDefFoundErrors on project Y with the same dependencies. The errors occur, because the hibernate jars seem not to be deployed on project Y. I have to put them jar by jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder that they get deployed for runtime, while in project X they are already deployed via dependencies. The difference: Project Y has a parent project.

Here the pom.xml s:

Working Project X:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>org.hibernate.tutorials</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-tutorial</artifactId>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>First Hibernate Tutorial</name>


        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.3.Final</version>
            </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.35</version>
    </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.4</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

              <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
                <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>     
    </project>
```

Project Y:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <parent>
        <artifactId>com-project</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.project</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </parent>
      <groupId>com.project.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>com-project-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
      <name>com-project-core Jersey Webapp</name>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.project.facade</groupId>
          <artifactId>com-project-facade</artifactId>
          <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.8.2</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

                    <!-- Hibernate -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.3.Final</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.35</version>
    </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.4</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
            </dependency>


      </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Project Y parent pom:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>com.project</groupId>
      <artifactId>com-project</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>pom</packaging>

      <name>com-project</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

      <modules>
        <module>com-project-core</module>
        <module>com-project-client</module>
        <module>com-project-facade</module>
      </modules>

      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      </properties>


    </project>
```

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052978/eclipse-java-lang-classnotfoundexception/1062435#1062435) attempt, but its all set.

Comment: What is the class that is not being found? Paste the stacktrace here.

Comment: Now I put just all jars in my WEB-INF/lib folder. But before it was 1. ClassNotFound Exception for jboss-logging.jar, then 2. ClassNotFound Exception for jta.jar and 3. ClassNotFound Exception for hibernate-commons-annotaions.jar. They were in may Mvane Dependencies folder, but since I put them into my WEB-INF/lib folder it worked.

Comment: The exception is expected since Project Y does not declare dependencies for JTA, Logging and Hibernate Annotations