# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class *.*.MainActivity with newrelic

Tags: android, newrelic, zendesk

I'm creating a kind of complex app that has multiple dependencies, I was using newrelic for a while with no problems, after that I wanted to add ZenDesk to the app, but when initializing the SDK , I was receiving a new relic error which was too weird! I tried for the sake of testing to remove newrelic from the app completely, so I removed compile `'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:5.3.1'` from the gradle file

the app doesn't work at all now! it crashes on start showing the error in the title:
**`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class *.*.MainActivity`**

when I add the newrelic back the app starts to work again!

I tried to to some digging about the problem and I found few suggestions about stopping gradle and cleaning the project and so saying the problem is probably a gradle cash or so, I tried everything, I even tried it on another machine, the problem persisted !

any ideas what is wrong??

**EDIT:**

manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.Main.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: ./gradlew --stop
./gradlew --refresh-dependencies  always solved the problem. did you try refresh-dependencies?

Comment: I deleted the whole folder and it did reinstall everything, and I tried the gradle stop, still the same, without the newrelic it crashes

Comment: I didn't try however the command refresh-dependencies

Comment: @HassanKhallouf Can you show your manifest ?

Comment: I added the manifest to the edit

Comment: no my friend I changed this after copying for stupid reasons, they match in my file, besides , why adding new relic makes it work?!

Comment: @HassanKhallouf Okay okay . try this

Answer (score 1):

```
android:name="com.myapp.Main.MainActivity"
```

I guess it is wrong

It will

```
android:name="com.orderme.MainActivity"
```

> The ClassNotFoundException is thrown when the Java Virtual Machine
>   (JVM) tries to load a particular class and the specified class cannot
>   be found in the classpath. The ClassNotFoundException is a checked
>   exception and thus, must be declared in a method or constructor’s
>   throws clause.

### What is the way

1. Verify that the name of the requested class is correct and that the
   appropriate .jar file exists in your classpath. If not, you must
   explicitly add it to your application’s classpath.
2. In case the **specified .jar file exists in your classpath then**, your
   application’s classpath is getting overriden and you must find the
   exact classpath used by your application.
3. In case the exception is caused by a third party class, you must
   identify the class that throws the exception and then, add the
   missing ***.jar files in your classpath***.

> [Eclipse - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052978/eclipse-java-lang-classnotfoundexception)

Answer (score 1):

As always, the solution is 99% stupid when it comes to programming XD

at the top of my ***gradle*** file there was this:
**`apply plugin: 'newrelic'`**

I just removed this line and it works now .

Comment: Some time it happens .Move ahead

Comment: you won't believe it, it happend to me also, the same problem with new relic plugin at the top.