# Eclipse/Grails - Tests don't run - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: eclipse, grails, groovy, junit, classnotfoundexception

I tried this before I asked: [topic: Eclipse ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052978/eclipse-java-lang-classnotfoundexception?newreg=febc73d418e449cdb52f3969ffcfd8d6)

and the main answer, but it didnt work.

My test class was not reconized when I ran a test. My test class is in a different source folder than the "src" main folder.

So, take the image: [image: My view]

OBS: I think it was because it's not a java class actualy but a groovy class, but I realy dont know how to deal. 
      It's not a maven project

Comment: Did you try to add this folder to buildpath?

Comment: Yes. But didnt work well