# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot

Appreciate your help on the error below. I got it when I restored my spring boot in eclipse. My main app is getting it:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/google/common/base/Function at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760) at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467) at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2128) at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.MainMethod.getMainMethod(MainMethod.java:57)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.MainMethod.getMainMethod(MainMethod.java:45)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.MainMethod.(MainMethod.java:39)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.getMainClassName(Restarter.java:145)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.(Restarter.java:135)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.initialize(Restarter.java:531)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationStartedEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:64)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:46)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:121)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.started(EventPublishingRunListener.java:60)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.started(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
>   at com.myagency.App.main(App.java:25) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function

Comment: Do you have Google Guava in your classpath?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052978/eclipse-java-lang-classnotfoundexception)