# Eclipse class not found exception

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, jvm

I am facing some challenges in Eclipse please help me. from last 5 years I am using visual studio but due to my academic requirement I am learning java and recently I installed eclipse in my machine and when I am modifying some code and trying to execute the test case, eclipse throwing classnotfoundexception. In visual studio, I used to rebuild or build it but here I am not able to find anything like that. attached images of the exception.

P.S. I did google it before asking question here but did not got any solution for my problem.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: The exception is telling you that the class `de.tuberlin.dima.`...`.TestTablePageStudents` cannot be found. Do you have a corresponding class in the correct package?

Comment: From the error the class not found is de.tuberlin.dima.minidb.test.io.tables.TestTablePageStudents, and from the image of your classes I can't see it in the package...

Comment: I am sorry forgot to attach the image of that class. yes that class exist.

Comment: Try to look at the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052978/eclipse-java-lang-classnotfoundexception, maybe can help

Answer (score 1):

From my recollection, my error was similar, but it's gone now. So I can say if it was the same exact issue. For me though, the solution was as simple as running "Project" --> "Clean..." and choosing "Clean all projects".  "Project" --> "Build Automatically" was already checked positive.