# Cannot see variables while debugging flash on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I keep having the issue when I try to debug a Flex/AS3 application on Eclipse IDE, as long as I hover over any variable the pop up window shows an error:

> An internal error occurred during: "Evaluating Flex expression...".
>   `java.lang.NullPointerException`

More details for the error, took me a while to find out in the eclipse log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2017-10-19 10:48:03.565
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Evaluating Flex expression...".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
at flash.tools.debugger.concrete.PlayerSession.pullUpActivationObjectVariables(PlayerSession.java:1007)
at flash.tools.debugger.concrete.PlayerSession.requestFrame(PlayerSession.java:984)
at flash.tools.debugger.concrete.DStackContext.populate(DStackContext.java:156)
at flash.tools.debugger.concrete.DStackContext.getThis(DStackContext.java:92)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.djapi.wrappers.ThreadSafeFrame.getThis(ThreadSafeFrame.java:121)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.model.FlexStackFrame.initVariables(FlexStackFrame.java:283)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.model.FlexStackFrame.getVariables(FlexStackFrame.java:410)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.expression.FlexStackContext.lookup(FlexStackContext.java:52)
at flash.tools.debugger.expression.VariableExp.evaluate(VariableExp.java:28)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.djapi.wrappers.ThreadSafeValueExp.evaluate(ThreadSafeValueExp.java:54)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.expression.FlexExpression.evaluate(FlexExpression.java:120)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.expression.FlexWatchExpressionDelegate$EvaluationJob.run(FlexWatchExpressionDelegate.java:103)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

The variable tab and expressions tab on eclipse both are empty: 
[screen shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH64E.png)

[image]

My environment:

- Eclipse 3.3.2
- Flash debugger 27.0.0.170 (debug version)
- Firefox 56.0.1 64-bit
- Flex builder 3

**I have tried** : reinstalling the flash debugger, and even rebuilt the Workspace for my Eclipse, no luck. Some ideas to fix this will be really appreciated.

Comment: not much to show on the screenshot image, regardless where I put the break point, the variables tab on eclipse is showing empty.

Comment: Eclipse 3.3 is 10 years old!

Comment: I know! i wont use it if i can, my work has some flash plugin on it. That's the main reason I use this. Flash on eclipse is a bit challenging.

Comment: Did you start a new Java app in Eclipse but now trying (while in same Java-mode) to process Flex code? Anyway to create a flex project and edit the AS files there?

Comment: yes, I did that while rebuilding the project.

Comment: @edisonouyang your _" I did that"_ is what exactly? I asked two questions...  Anyways you have the Flex SDK installed, etc? Anything [**useful in search**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Beclipse%5D+edit+actionscript)? For example one of the 32 answers to [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1052978/2057709) might help you, maybe... I say maybe cos not enough info to help re-create your issue. So to edit the AS3/Flex files you open Eclipse and then what options do you choose next until part where error is caused by hover...?

Comment: @edisonouyang try using a newer version of Flex (e.g. Flash Builder 4.7). Alternatively, give [FlashDevelop](http://flashdevelop.org/) try since you're on Windows (and it's free)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza, i finally saw the details of the error, I am trying 4.6 sdk now, for the debugger on my browser, it didn't say which version it is, i suppose just use the latest version then. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revert my browser and flash to the older version finally fixed the problem. Thanks all.