# Classnotfoundexception when copy paste a .ser file from a previous project to a new one

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project and serialized a class and got the .ser file on the same folder where the .classpath file is at. Now I created another project and copy paste the .ser from the previous one to the new one in the folder where the . classpath is at as well. But when I run the program I get classnotfoundexception. How can I go about this situation. I'm new to exclipse and I could use some help on what to do. Thank you.

Comment: Seems you have solved your problem for yourself.  But for future reference, you are more likely to get a helpful answer if you include (at least) the full stacktrace in your Java question.

Comment: It also helps if you search for an answer before asking a question.  For instance, when I googled "stackoverflow classnotfoundexception" the first search result was this Q&A - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1062435/139985 ... which basically answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Oh thanks by the way I figured it out. I added the first project via Java build path to the second one and imported the specific class! Now I can copy all the .ser files to the new project I'm working on.